# Capturing the data from different ports on a single port in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, sockets

I am making application in c# in which i am getting continuously data from different ports on a single port in packet format.Whatever data i am getting is continuous.I am getting data on port 24097 in packet format from different source port.For that i have created one thread for port 24097 which is continuously accepting data and as soon as it gets the data it passes to another thread from threadpool which writes that data to respective file.But my problem is that whenever one thread is writing data to respective file and if the next data comes for that file before completing first write operation ,then how i will know whether there is data writing operation is going on?Because once i have open the file i dont want to close it after writing of one thread.It should be open for writing data for another thread. please help me.

Comment: It's a very vague question and will take MUCH more than a single answer here to give a full answer. How much experiance do you have with multithreading, with packet captrue, what packet capture library are you using, etc?

Comment: Please consider doing some research and some experiments in the different aspects of your problem (threading, sockets, writing to files etc). When you get stuck then you can ask a much more focused question and people will gladly help you out.

Comment: I am creating application in that i have created one thread first which is receiving data continuously.As soon as it gets the data it passes to another thread which will do the further processing of data.But my problem is that i want to create different threads for different ports so that processing will be fast.But i am not getting output of that much quality as the it takes more time for processing. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using threadpooling? That might simplfy things a bit:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.But i already used threadpool but problem is that when there is multiple of threads then there is lot much need of synchronization.Suppose i am writing data of particular file and before completion of that operations if data of same file comes again then how i know that whether there is writing operation is going on that file?

Comment: Edit your original question to include that detail, people will be more able to help on here if you give them more detail to work with.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a ConcurrentQueue collection to store the data to be written to the file? :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a threadpool helps much here with the disk files.  One writing thread per disk makes more sense.  In each server/client thread, you could queue up, (blockingCollection), full data buffer instances to the writer thread and immediately new() another buffer for the next data to come in.  Each buffer instance could contain a reference to a per-port 'fileWriter' class instance that contains the file spec, file handle, write methods etc. so that the writer thread can open/write/close the file, perhaps as instructed by an enum. in each buffer.

The 'FileWriter' could contain a list/queue of its own, (any queue would do - it's only called from one thread), that allows the buffering up of buffer instances until a large chunk of data has built up and only then actually do the file write, so economising on head movements.